# Laptop hangs on resume from suspend (Acer Predator Ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: suspend, 23.10, resume

I have a Acer Predator laptop G9-791-73ZW running Ubuntu 23.10.

When I resume from a suspend I come back to this screen:

[image: Screen that comes back after resuming from suspend]

The computer will tend to hang here until I press ALT-F1 then ALT-F2 and it will come back to the login screen.  However, it will not accept any keyboard or mouse (trackpad or bluetooth mouse) input and I can't log in. I have to do a hard power off and reboot to get back into the system.

[image: screen after pressing ALT-F1/ALT-F2]

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to fix this, thanks.